# make a scrollbar always visible in a div - chrome

Tags: css

I've implemented infinite scrolling for the first time, but I can't get the scrollbar to show up initially when there is no overflow. I tried this in chrome:

```
#scrollarea-invalid {
overflow-y: scroll !important;
height: 350px;
}
```

how can I make the scrollbar always show up in this div, even if the content is less than 350px in this div?

Comment: `overflow: scroll;` should do the trick

Comment: how would that do the trick? there is no overflow to begin with...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just having the scrollbar visible will not allow you to react to the user trying to scroll down.  So you will need to actually make the content flow outside of the area and detect the scroll.
Try this:

```css
#scrollarea-invalid {
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 350px;
}
#scrollarea-content{
  min-height:101%;
}
```

```html
<div id='scrollarea-invalid'>
  <div id='scrollarea-content'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scroll bar doesn't. It's confusing !

Answer (score 54):

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  max-height:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
    <li>This is some content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, Cumulo Nimbus for this.  The -webkit-scrollbar and -webkit-scrollbar-thumb in my CSS did the trick to make the scrollbars appear again in Chrome. But I am curious why this was necessary. Why does Chrome ignore "overflow:scroll" and "overflow: auto" unless the CSS that you gave is included?

Comment: I have the same question as @BruceHill Why-o-Why?

Answer (score 9):

`overflow: auto` or
`overflow: scroll`
won't sometimes work. So we have to try webkit based code to resolve this issue.

Try the following code to display scroll bar always shown,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

this will always show the vertical and horizontal scroll bar on your page. If you need only a vertical scroll bar then put `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! Although 10px is phatttt!

Comment: Thanks @Kitson for your valuable comment.

Comment: I'm using this with a lower width. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution below is from W3Schools(Made some changes as per my requirements), but works for my case

```
/* Scrollbar Styling Start */
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background: #f1f1f1;
border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #888;
border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background: #555;
}
/* Scrollbar Styling Ends */
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my page, where to see [videos](https://cinemalogy.com/movies/aquaman-2/) list we have to scroll. I was afraid that the visitor think that there only one video.

Using ::-webkit-scrollbar and ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb is the proven solution.